# Trying to count records in SSRS from different data sets

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report that combines 5 reports into one.  Each report is populated from a different stored procedure.  The first page is a summary that is to provide a record count from each report.  I've created fields in the stored procedure that provides the counts for each individual report: phycount and nonphyscount.  I'm trying to create a table similar to this:

[image]

Active comes from one data set, Initial comes from another, Recert comes from another, etc.

I've been playing around with the Lookup and LookupSet but I'm just getting errors, plus I'm not sure if that's even the right direction.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The input is a single value I assume? Have you tried creating one proc to run all of your counts and then return that as a dataset?

Comment: I had thought of that, but I think it ends up being even more difficult.  The stored procs return counts as a field, but these fields don't get input into a table(which I'm not allowed to create).  I would have to create one proc that runs all the queries from the 5 other procs, and this would really increase the run time of the report.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I thought you had that as the first page of the report. Can you store the counts in a table? I don't see how you would get the counts from the other reports at run time without running their queries.

Comment: It is the first page of the report.  Are you referring to storing the counts in a table in SSRS?  I'm not allowed to create tables in SQL.  Originally I created a separate table with the count from each data set and then placed these tables one on top of the other to make it look like one table.  But this never looked right and I'd like to have just one table with the counts from all the data sets.

Comment: If the fields aren't going to change, I would just create a table and do a LookUp for each value. Set the source for the table to the simplest dataset since you won't use it. Remove the detail from the table and add more header rows (with no grouping or detail lines) so you have four rows - one for the headers and then the 3 lines of lookups. The design view would look just like your table above (but with *EXPR* for the numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Lookup and Lookupset are more for getting specific values out of a dataset. Very useful but not necessary for what you're trying to accomplish.

You can use aggregate functions SUM and COUNT to accomplish what you want to do. The cool thing about these functions is you can actually embed IIF statements inside of them.

I'm not sure exactly how your datasets look and are named but it would be something like this...

> SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "PhyCount", 1, 0), "Active")

The sum function goes through every row of your dataset and sums the values you pass to it. The iif statement checks to see if the type field in the dataset is "PhyCount". If so, it returns 1, if not, 0. Since this will happen for every row, your SUM function will return a count of each row with status active.

edit: "Active" after the iif statement specifies the name of the dataset.

EDIT AGAIN: This solution apparently does not work in SSRS 2008.

Comment: I think I figured it out, and if I'm correct it wasn't too bad.  I created a table and then added a Group.  For each row group I was able to call the count field for each data set: =Sum(Fields!physicianct.Value, "ds1licensettest")

Comment: @Lucky--I tried your solution but I got an error that the scope parameter is not valid for an aggregate function.  I tried this: Sum(IIF(Fields!TypeValue = "phycount", 1, 0), "Active").  Your solution sounds interesting and I'd like to get this to work as well.

Comment: Great, if the simple sum works for you great. I love getting SSRS to do things it doesn't want to do! I just tested this and it works: =SUM(IIF(Fields!Staff_Name.Value="Blow, Joe", 1, 0), "DataSet1")

Comment: Make sure your fields is formatted like "Fields!Type.Value". I think that was a typo above. Also make sure that field is in the dataset you are doing a Sum against.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm using: =Sum(IIF(Fields!physicianct.Value = 1, 1, 0), "dataset1"), but I'm getting the same scope error.

Comment: Oh, it might be due to your SSRS version!